# how to call inner class's method from static main() method

Tags: java, polymorphism, inner-classes

Trying to create 1 interface and 2 concrete classes inside a Parent class. This will qualify the enclosing classes to be Inner classes.

```
public class Test2 {

       interface A{
             public void call();
       }

       class B implements A{
             public void call(){
                   System.out.println("inside class B");
             }
       }

       class C extends B implements A{
             public void call(){
                   super.call();
             }
       }


       public static void main(String[] args) {
              A a = new C();
              a.call();

       }
}
```

Now I am not really sure how to create the object of class C inside the static main() method and call class C's call() method.
Right now I am getting problem in the line :  `A a = new C();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here the inner class is not static, so you need to create an instance of outer class and then invoke new,

```
A a = new Test2().new C();
```

But in this case, you can make the inner class static,

```
static class C extends B implements A
```

then it's ok to use,

```
A a = new C()
```

Answer (score 4):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

So you need to use :

```
A a = new Test2().new C();
```

Refer the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
 A a = new Test2().new C();
```