# How to call an object within an object

Tags: java, oop

I have this class called MAN, PUNCH and Test

the PUNCH object is a field within the MAN class and everything works fine.

But in the Test class, I want to access a method of the PUNCH class. How do I go about in doing this? Thanks

Comment: `manObject.punchObject.punchMethod();` tried that ?

Comment: Well thats very basic and there are lots of similar questions and answers

Comment: You might wanna look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954599/how-to-call-inner-classs-method-from-static-main-method) thead if you have further questions

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 3 classes and you want to access nested methods, they have to be public or public static

if you have a getPunch() in the MAN class, you can access the MAN object and let him fire the punch.

Your man class has to have the field punch and have to have a way to create the punch object.

```
public class Man {
   Punch punch;
   public man(){
      punch = new Punch();
   }
   public Punch getPunch(){
      return punch();
   }
}
```

then you can access the punch object via the getPunch

```
Man man = new Man();
man.getPunch().somePunchMethod();
```

or create a reference to the punch field, and use it to access punch methods

```
Man man = new Man();
Punch punch = man.getPunch();
punch.somePunchMethod();
```

Comment: but he wants to work with inner classes. You provide an answere for the case, that the method is within his man class, but not the nested punch class

Comment: He did not ask for a nested class, he asked for a nested field

Comment: well if thats the case he would instanciate his PUNCH object. PUNCH punch = new PUNCH() and afterwards he would have to create a getter function within the MAN class wich returns his PUNCH object. edit it and I give you an upvote

Comment: yep. Its very basic and should be cleared for every novice. But I dont think that the author worked with setters at all. Also have a look at my edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer if you want to access a method in a nested class.

```
 //Initialise outer-class
 Man man = new Man();
 //initialise nested-class
 MAN.PUNCH punch = man.new PUNCH();

 //resolve the method of your nested class
 punch.methodInPUNCH();
```

If you want to accsess your Punchobject wich is instanciated in your MAN class it should look like this:

```
   public class MAN{

   PUNCH punch;

     public MAN(){ 
      this.punch = new PUNCH();
    }

    public PUNCH getPunch(){
    return punch;
    }
  }
```

Afterwards to acsess your `method()` in `PUNCH`:

```
MAN man = new Man();
PUNCH punch = man.getPunch();
punch.yourMethodInPunch();
```

Comment: the creation of a punch object should be directly. Instead of "PUNCH punch = new PUNCH(); this.punch = punch;" you can directly create a punch object like "this.punch = new PUNCH();". The this is optional since there is no other reference to the punch field.

Comment: I know but its easier to understand without inlining it. Its a term of programming style I would said. I edit it anyways