# Java ,import not resolved,inheritance,inner class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Begging java programming recently, run into an error. please help

Have two classes , PersonTest.java:

```
 public class PersonTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1=new Person("dummy","sdymmt","20","male","washington");
    System.out.println("Name: "+person1.getName());
    System.out.println("Surname: "+person1.getSurname());
    System.out.println("Age: "+person1.getAge());
    System.out.println("Gender:" +person1.getGender());
    System.out.println("Birthplace: "+person1.getBirthplace());
    Person person2= new Person(400);
    System.out.println("Income:"+person2.getX()+" mije leke");
    System.out.println("Tax:"+person2.Taksat()+" mije leke");
    Student student1= new Student("adsd","zedsdsadza");
    System.out.println("emri"+student1.getEmer());
}

}
```

and also Person.java :

```
public class Person {
    private String Name;
    private String Surname;
    private String Age;
    private String Gender;
    private String Birthplace;
    private double x;
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(String Name, String Surname, String Age, String Gender, String Birthplace) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Surname = Surname;    
        this.Age = Age; 
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Birthplace = Birthplace;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return Surname;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    public String getBirthplace() {
        return Birthplace;
    }

    public Person(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    double Taksat() {
        return (0.1 * x);
    }

    public class Student extends Person {
        private String University;
        private String Faculty;

        public Student(String Universiteti, String Fakulteti) {
            super(Name, Surname, Age, Gender, Birthplace);
            this.Faculty = Fakulteti;
            this.University = Universiteti;
        }

        public String getFaculty() {
            return Faculty;
        }

        public String getUniversity() {
            return University;
        }
    }
}
```

Two classes are in the same default package. How to fix the fact that the test class doesn't  recognize the inner class student as a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call inner class's method from static main() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954599/how-to-call-inner-classs-method-from-static-main-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested non static class are called `Inner Classes` those classes cannot live without the `Outer class` (which wrapped them).

[**Java docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this
>   syntax:
>
> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

Try using:

```
Person.Student student = person1.new Student(PARAMETERS);
```

**Important Mark:**

Of course, you should highly consider that this is not a good design, because you may want this classes to be visible outside of the `Person class` but also because `Person.Student` inherits from `Person`, which it's already contains the `Student class`, which usually looks like a loop or a circle relationship, which usually not a good idea for the first place.

Comment: Thank you my friend.It worked very well.This was an exercise that a professor let from class to home and said to continue on the design he gave, don't know why. I wanted to do the class separately, person by itself,student by itself, and than just extend.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no Student class.  Since it nested, it's Person.Student